# How to split a string by whitespaces and punctuations, but keep the punctuations?

Tags: python, string

If I want to use re.split in Python to achieve this goal, how to do this?
e.g: 'donald trump! donald? trump' -->
`['donald','trump','!','donald','?','trump']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a regex that matches either words `(\w+)` or 
question mark (`?`) or  exclamation mark (`!`).

```
>>> s="donald trump! donald? trump"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|\?|\!',s)
['donald', 'trump', '!', 'donald', '?', 'trump']
```

Comment: or `\w+ | [,.!?;:]` with more punctuation included as necessary

Comment: THX! That's what I need!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to split a string by spaces in python try using python's string split().

```
string = 'donald trump! donald? trump'

print(string.split(' '))
```

Output:

```
['donald ', 'trump!', 'donald? ', 'trump']
```

Comment: This output does not match the output described in the question